# Error in flutter while using firebase_ml_vision

Tags: flutter, firebase-mlkit

When I use or add firebase_ml_vision in pubspec.yaml file, my app showing these error.

If I remove firebase_ml_vision in pubspec yaml, eveything goes fine.

I just followed all process from integrating firebase to add `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:16.1.1'` to app/build.gradle.

But I've just stuck in here.

I have no idea how to solve it.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[19.1.
  0]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

  Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-image-label:18.0.4 -> com.google.android.gms:play-servic
  es-vision-common@[19.1.0], but play-services-vision-common version was 19.1.2.
                                                                                
  The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
  ifact with the issue.
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@{strictly 24.1.0}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common@{strictly 19.1.2}
  -- Project 'app' depends on project 'firebase_ml_vision' which depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@20.0.
  0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition@{strictly 16.1.1}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition@16.1.1
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-bom@26.0.0 
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-image-label@{strictly 18.0.4}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-bom@{strictly 26.0.0}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision@{strictly 20.1.2}

  For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
  endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
  github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = true }" to your bu
  ild.gradle file.
```

My build.gradle at project level

```
buildscript {
    '''
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    }
}
```

My build.gradle at app level

```
'''
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

'''
android {
    '''
    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        '''
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        '''
    }
    '''
}
'''
dependencies {
   '''
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:16.1.1'
}
```

Comment: It's probably due to play-services-mlkit-text-recognition and firebase_ml_vision has different version requirements on play-services-vision-common.

Why do you need both? The latter one is deprecated by the new ML Kit.
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration/android

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve a similar problem using firebase-bom:24:0.0 instead of 26:0.0.

Answer (score 0):

we made some changes to Firebase ML Kit to better distinguish the on-device APIs from cloud based APIs. "ML Kit"(without firebase branding) contains all the on-device APIs. [Here's](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration/android) the migration guide from firebase mlkit to mlkit.

For this specific dependency issue, there is an known issue with the firebase mlkit dependency. There's an explanation [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#mlkit-self-serve-fixes).

Remove the firebase mlkit vision, depend on com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:16.1.1 and use the MLKit APIs should be the right thing to do.